# Add ALU Result of this picture

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

Could someone please explain to me how could I get the ALU result for this question? I've already got the input answer but I'm not too sure what should I get for the ALU result here. I know Shift left 2 should have X4 bit but is it the answer = input * 2^4? I tried to search for answer online but things are just getting confusing. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: A "shift left 2" would shift left 2 times, which is a multiplication by 4. So not the `*2^4` that you mention (that's `*16`)

Comment: Hi @SepRoland thanks for your reply, so is 25120 * 2^2 instead?

Comment: The ALU block says "Add." So I think you need to add 25120 and (25120 * 2^2), assuming that 25120 is supplied to both inputs. Or perhaps the "shift left 2" is a control signal to the ALU? But then why "Add" is written on the ALU? This figure is confusing. The second input cannot just magically shift left; it needs a shifter to do that. Or is it already shifted left? If the intention was to add two numbers, then "Add" should be an input to the ALU as a control signal, not written on it like that.

Comment: This question is unclear. What if shift left 2 means the number 2 shifted left? Which is 4 plus 25120 to give 25124. That is certainly one way to look at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think x4 is right.

However, if this ALU is used for address calculation, the alu x4 more.
'25120' could be a index for 4-byte aligned address.

If the result of alu is used for memory address, it makes sense.
But, I am not sure...